# Postgresql DBGlass cant find the user

Tags: postgresql-9.3

I open tasksdb database from here
[image]

then I create a user 'admin' with 'password'
[image]

then this is the DBGlass output I get 
[image]

I cant figure out what I'm doing wrong.